# Rotate SKSpriteNode to Another SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to rotate one sprite node to another. It rotates but not well. How can I fix it?

I have tried:

```
let blaster = self.childNode(withName: blaster)
let currentBlasterPosition = blaster!.position
let angle = atan2(currentBlasterPosition.y - cubes[0].position.y, currentBlasterPosition.x - cubes[0].position.x)
let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle + 90, duration: 0.0)

blaster!.run(SKAction.sequence([rotateAction]))
```

The `SKSpriteNode` is rotating for about -30 to 30 degrees from the point it should be (depending on its position).

[image: game sprites screenshot]

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract the target position's coordinates from the origin coordinates? (e.g. `cubes[0].position.y - currentBlasterPosition.y`, not the other way around)

Comment: no, that makes it even worse ;)

Comment: +90?  You need to work in radians, not degrees

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dealing with calculating the angles yourself, use [SKConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint) for that task.
Assuming your `cubes` is an Array of SKNodes:

```swift
let constraint = SKConstraint.orient(to: cubes[0], offset: SKRange(constantValue:0))
blaster!.constraints = [constraint]
```

You will have to do this just once, instead of every frame. The constraint is automatically applied every frame.
To remove it, set the blaster's constraints back to `nil`:

```swift
blaster!.constraints = nil
```